# Can the vsphhere Hypervisor be encrytpted

Tags: security, virtual-machine, vmware, vsphere

- I know that vmware's Vsphere VM's can be encrypted using a KMS server but can the actual drive which vsphere is hosted on be encrypted? In Microsoft the hyper-visor host can be encrypted if bit-locker is enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not explicitly. You can, however, use Secure Boot to ensure that only signed code is ran: https://blogs.vmware.com/vsphere/2017/05/secure-boot-esxi-6-5-hypervisor-assurance.html

Comment: Thank you for your input, Kyle.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Kyle Rudy's vmware link the following is good to note:
https://blogs.vmware.com/vsphere/2017/05/secure-boot-esxi-6-5-hypervisor-assurance.html

TPM and TXT

The question always comes up in customer conversations of “Does this require TPM or TXT??”. The answer is no. They are mutually exclusive. Secure Boot for ESXi is purely a function of the UEFI firmware and the validation of cryptographically signed code. Period.

Note that TPM 1.2 and TPM 2.0 are two vastly different implementations. They are not backwards compatible. There is support, via 3rd parties like HyTrust, for TPM 1.2 in ESXi 6.5.

TPM 2.0 is not supported in 6.5.
Standard BIOS firmware vs UEFI firmware

Typically, switching your hosts from their standard (legacy) BIOS firmware to UEFI firmware in some operating systems will cause issues. With ESXi, you can switch with no modification to ESXi. If you have installed 6.5 using standard BIOS and you want to try out Secure Boot then in the host firmware you can switch and ESXi will come up.